# Symfony2 | Why controller action executes twice?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Its been few days I'm facing a weird behavior with Symfony.
I have an action in which for some reason I need to store a random value as form nonce in the session. The nonce is passed to the twig template to be used by an ajax function.

While sending nonce to the corresponding action a difference nonce value is examined and therefore the request rejects.

Tests showed that the action is executed twice by Symfony hence a new nonce will be stored without updating the front-end. I couldn't determine the reason.

After hundreds of tests I figured out that a minor change in the route could fix the problem but I'm not convinced this is the ultimate solution and I couldn't find the root cause.

Anyone can help?

here is the problematic code:

```
/**
 * 
 * Condo Apartments management 
 * 
 * @Route("/condo/apartment")
 */
class ApartmentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Index Condo Apartments
     * 
     * @Route("/edit/{id}/{apartment}", name="edit_apartment")
     * @Route("/manage/{id}", name="manage_apartments")
     * @ParamConverter("apartment", class="RimakishCondominiumBundle:Apartment", options={"mapping":{"apartment"="id"}})
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function indexApartmentsAction( Request $request, Complex $complex, Apartment $apartment=null){


    $session = $request->getSession();
    $nonce = sha1(uniqid());
    if($session->has('nonce')){
        $session->remove('nonce');
    }

    $session->set('nonce', $nonce);
```

I just changed the first route as follows and it worked. Now I need to know the root cause of this issue.

```
* @Route("/{id}/{apartment}/edit", name="edit_apartment")
```

Comment: I am using Symfony 2.8

Comment: The simplest reason is usually the correct answer. It seems likely your ajax function is calling the URL twice. You should debug the full request - it should be very obvious if this method is being called more than once via ajax.

Comment: Thanks Richard, but that was part of my tests. I put a strict monitoring on server-client communication to make sure there is no extra queries sent from browser to server. I also checked the number of Doctrine queries on server side which was identical. Please remember that ajax calls another action and I modified the Route to fix problem. If the ajax was problematic changing the route couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few days ago, and as Richard said, the problem was to be found in the js part of my app.
In my case, I'm using the on() jquery method because of the dynamic content in my page, and event handlers were "accumulating" in some specific circumstances.
I had to use the off() method and this solved my multiple ajax calls.

My code looks like this:

```
// A function executed when clicking a button with class ".modal-form"
$('body').on('click', '.modal-form', function (e) {
    //...(loading a form in a modal)
    //calling a function that initializes my form
    initializeForm();
    //...
});
```

To solve my problem I had to add `$( "body" ).off( "submit", "**" );` in my function initializeForm to clear all event handlers attached to the element with id "my-form"

```
function initializeForm(){
    $( "body" ).off( "submit", "**" ); // I had to add this to avoid sending multiple ajax
                                       //requests in case the button with ".modal-form"
                                       //class has been clicked several times
    $('body').on('submit', '#my-form', function(e) {
        //...
        $.ajax({
            // That request was being sent several times
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roubi, please check my comment on Richard's comment